# What advantage does a docking station have over a USB 3.0 hub?

Tags: laptop, usb, multiple-monitors, docking-station

I use my Dell laptop at home by connecting it to a single large monitor. In such a scenario what is the technical advantage / use-case for a docking station?

So I understand that if I have several peripherals but only 2 or 3 USB ports then a USB hub does a desired function. But unless I want to split my HDMI output over several external displays what's the use-case for docking stations?

The reason I ask is that docking stations seem to be also several times more expensive than a USB hub. What gives?

What additional function do the perform?

Answer (score 1):

A USB hub is a device that connects to the USB host, with either a USB-A or USB-C connector to allow connection to a handful oof other USB devices.  Some hubs will provide internal Ethernet and audio along with USB-A and one or two USB-C ports.  If there are more than just USB ports, and often no video, then this might step beyond a hub and into a mimi-dock.

A hub will be something that has no video.  When it handles video then it's a dock.  There's two ways to handle video in a dock.  It can use USB-C that supports DisplayPort.  My experience tells me this DisplyPort (or DP) will often be converted to HDMI or VGA.  If there is a DP port with the DP port the the dock may be able to suppoort two independent displays.  That depends on the host machine GPU.  These hosts require USB-C connection to the host.

A different kind of USB dock can provide video using the DisplayLink video chip.  This is not gaming quality chip but many people in need of a simple added screen for office productivity and sound.  These kinds of docks typically use the USB-A port to connect to the PC.  This means sound, video, keyboard, mouse, networking, and perhaps more all plugged-in at once.

Goin up in video capability is the eGPU dock.  They center around a high end GPU for powering a screen or three at high frame rates for gaming or getting the most out of stock information.  These  eGPU docks will often have power available to charge the laptop, cellphone, and other accessories.  While storage is not often included on the dock there will be option to connection them by eSATA, USB-C, Thunderbolt, or Network share.  It is this kind of dock that offered more USB-C port than any other because the system is running on Thunderbolt.  USB-C don't have the means to understand multiple USB-C devices at a time.  There are issues of the hierarchy.  The use of USB-A and USB-B enforce hierarchy.  USB-C makes this ambiguous in places.  To void this means keeping a single PC at the core, then use USB-C where peer-to-peer communications is needed.

A step up on this, or  step to the side, is instead of using a eGPU dock there is the used of a PCIe chassis for a dock.  These will offer the option to an an eGPU for those that want it, more interface ports, or more storage.  The case will have as many PCIe slots that one can buy, usually one, two, or the.  People wanting more video can pack two GPU cards.  Those wanting more storage can pack in interface cards for external storage or cards with storage of their own.  There will be a potential for a bottleneck of data to and from the host machine from the Thunderbolt 2 or 3 cable used to coonect this all.  There's a potential to address this by bonding another Thunderbolt connection.

The advantages of a USB dock are having the ability to add additional peripheral interfaces.  Consider what you need to plug in.  There's also the ability to add extra video.  A low grade video can be added with DisplayLink, a USB-to-video option.  Next in line are GPUs in a dedicated Thunderbolt box.  These will give access to some midrange eGPUs for gamining or whatever.  Higher end is a Thunderbolt PCIe chassis that allows any of a number of desktop sized GPUs in a case, the connections on the case will be for multiple displys, USB-C devices, or whatever PCIe cards are installed.  It doesnot have to be a GPU but instead drive storage, networking and other interfaces, or what ever.

Docking stations cost more because they do more.  A hub is just splitting off USB to get keyboard, mice, Ethernet and maybe some USB storage.  Stepping up to video means asking what kind of video.  Can your computer do well on it's own then put it on an external screen, maybe two.  More than that and you likely need a higher end dock with a GPU or two.  Need storage with the video or instead of, then look at that path.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! So if I have just one large external monitor then the video capabilities of the docking station are useless. Ie I don't need to split video out from my laptop.

Comment: " Thanks for the great answer! So if I have just one large external monitor then the video capabilities of the docking station are useless. Ie I don't need to split video out from my laptop. " That depends.  If the laptop has a GPU that is not all that great then adding a better one can still be beneficial.  Minimizing the connections to the dock can help with an eGPU too, just run USB and power rather than USB, power, and video.  For laptops that have USB-C that contain power, USB, and video in one cable though this may not be a benefit in any way.

Comment: Thanks! I never realised a docking station as a tool for boosting GPU capabilities! I always thought of it as a passive "routing" device not as a processing device!